# Función para operador "+=" en Matlab

Tags: python, matrices, matlab, operador, operador-incremento

Necesito hacer en matlab una operación equivalente al "+=" en python. He estado buscando pero al parecer matlab no tiene un equivalente, no sé porqué. ¿Alguien conoce un método para generar una función que haga la operación equivalente? Es para un programa que resuelve Sudokus por backtracking. Este es mi código. La idea es que se detenga hasta que Seq0=0 (cuando ya no haya ceros). Se parte de una matriz inicial, Se parte en filas, y se introduce en un ciclo para buscar la solución por fuerza bruta. Generando arreglos de forma semialeatoria hasta dara con la solución exacta.

```
clc;
S=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,6; 0,2,0,9,0,0,0,0,0; 0,3,8,0,5,4,1,0,0; 
    9,0,0,5,0,0,0,3,0; 0,0,0,0,1,8,0,6,7; 4,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0;
    7,1,3,8,6,2,0,5,0; 5,0,3,6,2,7,0,0,0; 6,0,2,0,3,0,8,9,4]

hS1=S(1,1:9); hS2=S(2,1:9); hS3=S(3,1:9);
hS4=S(6,1:9); hS5=S(5,1:9); hS6=S(6,1:9);
hS7=S(7,1:9); hS8=S(8,1:9); hS9=S(9,1:9);

L9=1:9; iteraciones=0;
S1=(reshape(S,1,[])); S1eq0=~ismember(S1,L9);
Seq0=1; remS=find(S1eq0); lenS=length(remS)

while Seq0 > 0
    iteraciones=iteraciones+1
    for kk=9:89
        fila=fix(kk/9);
        columna=rem(kk,9)+1; %para evitar error debido al valor columna=0
        if columna<=9 && columna<=9
            if S(fila, columna)==0
                for value=1:9
                    if ~ismember(value,S(fila,:))
                        if ~ismember ( value,cat(2, hS1(:,columna),...
                                hS2(:,columna), hS3(:,columna),...
                                hS4(:,columna), hS5(:,columna),...
                                hS6(:,columna), hS7(:,columna),...
                                hS8(:,columna), hS9(:,columna)) )
                            square1 = [];
                            square2 = [];
                            square3 = [];
                            if fila<=3
                                if columna<=3
                                    for ii=1:3
                                        square1=[S(ii,1:3)]; %aqui es donde quiero hacer la operacion +=
                                    end
                                elseif columna<=6
                                    for ii=1:3
                                        square1=[S(ii,4:6)]; %y aqui
                                    end
                                else
                                    for ii=1:3
                                        square1=[S(ii,7:9)]; y aqui, etc...
                                    end
                                end

                            elseif fila<=6
                                if columna<=3
                                    for ii=4:6
                                        square2=[S(ii,1:3)];
                                    end
                                elseif columna<=6
                                    for ii=4:6
                                        square2=[S(ii,4:6)];
                                    end
                                else
                                    for ii=4:9
                                        square2=[S(ii,7:9)];
                                    end
                                end

                            else
                                if columna<=3
                                    for ii=7:9
                                        square3=[S(ii,1:3)];
                                    end
                                elseif columna<=6
                                    for ii=7:9
                                        square3=[S(ii,4:6)];
                                    end
                                else
                                    for ii=7:9
                                        square3=[S(ii,7:9)];
                                    end
                                end

                            if ~ismember(value, cat(2,square1,square2,square3))
                                S(fila,columna)=value;
                            end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    S1=(reshape(S,1,[])); S1eq0=~ismember(S1,L9);
    remS=find(S1eq0); Seq0=length(remS)
    S
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Matlab no tiene esa opción. Sé que [lo han discutido](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.soft-sys.matlab/c/2yJP5hjCmqw?pli=1) pero, debido a que matlab a) pasa argumentos por valor y no por referencia, y b) manipula todo como matrices, ese operador sería ambiguo y el resultado esperado es inesperado.

Octave, la alternativa open-source de Matlab, [sí tiene](https://hyperpolyglot.org/numerical-analysis) un equivalente *similar*.

Comment: La cuestión es que es un trabajo que debo entregar, y es obligatorio hacerlo en Matlab. Personalmente hubiera preferido usar python, pues el operador de acumulamiento es relativamente simple de usar. De hecho me estoy basando en un código en python que encontré, el cual modifiqué para incluir el operador +=, y funcionó igual. No digo que sea mi código, sólo que logré modificar la línea 90 y similares para incluir este operador. Este es el enlace (https://www.101computing.net/backtracking-algorithm-sudoku-solver/)